# Different placement in the or function gave 2 different solution. What is the problem?

Tags: python, list

```
print(list(range(1, 100)))
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    if (i%3==0) or (i%5==0):
        sum += i
print(sum)
```

---

```
print(list(range(1, 100)))
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 100):
    if i% (3 or 5) == 0:
        sum += i
print(sum)
```

---

I got 2 different answers here. Not sure what's the difference

Comment: "or" doesn't work the way shown in the second sample. `(3 or 5)` will always evaluate `3`.

Comment: What do you think `i % (3 or 5)` does? You might want to read up on the doc here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: notwithstanding the fact that `or` doesn't work that way, even following PEMDAS, what is in parentheses goes first. In a python console, just type `3 or 5` and see what the result is. That will answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if i % (3 or 5) == 0:` will always return 3 because the `or` is comparison between 3 and 5 and 3 is the first value. Programming languages *generally* have you type out the entire statement between `or`

So essentially, you can't do it "shorthand" in this way (AFAIK) :/